# Error 1054 unknown column in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly complex SQL statement which didn't work and I need to fix. I am trying something like the following

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  COALESCE(
    (
      SELECT
        t2.value
      FROM
        my_table AS t2
      WHERE
        t2.id = t1.id AND
        t2.ref = 'aa'
    ),
    (
      SELECT
        SUM(t3.value) AS value
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            t4.value
          FROM
            my_table as t4
          WHERE
            t4.id = t1.id AND
            t4.ref IN ('bb', 'cc')
        ) AS t3
     )
  )
FROM
  my_table AS t1
WHERE
  id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I need to COALESCE function to just get the first value with a certain ref. But then, for two particular refs I need the sum of the values (sigh).

I used to calculate the sum of two more COALESCE functions: for ref bb and for ref cc. The reason I used the COALESCE function was that because it was a sum I had to use 0 if the value for either bb or cc didn't exist. The mistake was that if neither value for bb or cc existed the sum was 0 (rather than null) and the external COALESCE function returned 0 instead of null.

So, I am trying to refactor the statement as above but I get the error

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.id' in 'where clause' on line 23
```

Any advice?

EDIT

Forget the COALESCE function. The following returns the same error

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  (SELECT
     SUM(t3.value) AS value
   FROM
     (
       SELECT
         t4.value
       FROM
         my_table as t4
       WHERE
         t4.id = t1.id AND
         t4.ref IN ('bb', 'cc')
     ) AS t3
  ) AS value
FROM
  my_table AS t1
WHERE
  id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the results of subqueries appear as tables to the outer query. You're doing what boils down to:

```
SELECT foo         // query #3
FROM (
   SELECT bar      // query #2
   FROM (
      SELECT baz   // query #1
      FROM t1
   ) AS t2
) AS t3
```

Inner query #1 returns a table with a single column called `baz` to query #2. That query tries to select a column named `bar` from that virtual table, but there's only baz in there. So that's one "unknown column" error.

Same applies for query #3 (outer). It wants a field named `foo` from a table which only has a `bar` in it.

If you want your query to work, you'd need something more like:

```
SELECT foo
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(....) AS foo  // <--note the alias here
    etc...
```

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. I think all the fields in my query are named correctly. Anyway, I have tried removing the COALESCE function and just keep the second SELECT (the one with the SUM) and still have the same issue